# Can you change the value according to the date?

Tags: date

Is there a formula that can change the value according to the date of the day?

Examaple: in April it's 10 and in November it's 5, August is 6.

Kind regards
Karsten

Answer (score 1):

A mapping table will do this. It could be implemented as a persisted table, a view, a common table expression (CTE), a CASE expression of maybe some other ways. Reuse, volatility of values and performance, not to mention DBMS capability, will guide the implementation choice.